# nginxでユーザディレクトリを実装した際のドキュメントルートの変更について

Tags: nginx

現在、nginxでApacheのUserDirと同じ動きをするWEBサーバを構築しているのですが、
ユーザディレクトリのドキュメントルート指定について教えて頂きたいことがあります。

`https://hogehoge.com/`にアクセスした場合は、`/var/www/html`配下の物を、`https://hogehoge.com/~fugafuga`にアクセスした場合は、`/home/fugafuga/public_html`配下の物をそれぞれ表示するようにするため、下記のようなコンフィグを書きました。

```
server {

～

root /var/www/html;

    #UserDir 
        location ~ ^/~(?<userdir_user>.+?)(?<userdir_uri>/.*)?$ {
                index   index.html index.htm index.php;
                alias /home/$userdir_user/public_html$userdir_uri;
                autoindex on;

        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                limit_req zone=limit_req_by_ip burst=10 nodelay;

                location ~ \.php$ {
                        include         fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $request_filename;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                        fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
                        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
                        include fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_buffers 256 128k;
                        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                        fastcgi_read_timeout 120s;
                }
        }

    #Index
        location / {
                        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                        limit_req zone=limit_req_by_ip burst=10 nodelay;

                        location ~ \.php$ {
                                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
                                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
                                fastcgi_index index.php;
                                #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $request_filename;
                                include fastcgi_params;
                                fastcgi_buffers 256 128k;
                                fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                                fastcgi_read_timeout 120s;
                        }
                }

～

}
```

このコンフィグであれば、意図した動きをしてくれると思っていたのですが、テストを行った際に1点問題が発生しました。

`https://hogehoge.com/~fugafuga/index.html`にて

```
<script src="/js/xxx.js>
```

のようにスクリプトのパスを指定すると、`https://hogehoge.com/~fugafuga/js/xxx.js`ではなく、`https://hogehoge.com/js/xxx.js`を読み込もうとします。

これは、rootでドキュメントルートを`/var/www/html`として指定し、ユーザディレクトリはあくまでaliasを張っているだけですので、コンフィグ通りに動いてくれてはいるのですが、これを期待通りの`https://hogehoge.com/~fugafuga/js/xxx.js`を読み込もうとするような仕組みを作るには、どのように変更してあげれば良いでしょうか・・・？

色々と確認したのですが、私が観測できる限りではうまい解決策が見つかりませんでした。

大変恐縮ですが、お知恵を拝借したく存じます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

単純にHTML中で指定したファイルパスの記述ミスが原因かと思われます。

`https://hogehoge.com/~fugafuga/index.html`から
`https://hogehoge.com/~fugafuga/js/xxx.js`を参照するなら、正しい記述は

```html
<script src="./js/xxx.js">
```

となるはずです。絶対パスと**相対パス**の違いに気をつけてください。

`./`で始めると「同じディレクトリ以下にあるファイルやフォルダを参照する」相対パスで、`/`で始めてしまうと絶対パスになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます

HTMLについて疎いため、分からなかったのですが、コーディング規約として絶対パスを使用すべきでない、ということでしょうか

頂いた回答へ更に質問させて頂く形になり大変恐縮ですが、仮にuserAが作成した　~userA/js/xxx.jsファイルをUserBがHTML内でsrc="../userA/js/xxx.jsと指定するとUserBがUserAのjsを使えてしまうという認識で良かったでしょうか

これを防ぐ良い方法はありますでしょうか・・・？